# fabric8 docker-maven-plugin capAdd fails with "unknown capability to add"

Tags: maven, docker, fabric8

**The Context** : trying to setup an automated integration test-suite where maven can start and stop docker images before and after tests run on a CI server. Decided to go with fabric8 because of the extensive documentation.

fabric8io.github.io/docker-maven-plugin/docker-start.html says

> capAdd a list of add elements to specify kernel parameters to add to the container.

I assume the syntax is similar to *ADD local-artifact-version.jar app.jar*
but this isn't working.

**The Problem** : when I run *mvn clean package docker:build docker:start -Ddocker.follow=true*
I get an error `io.fabric8.maven.docker.access.hc.http.HttpRequestException: Cannot start container [sha1]: Unknown capability to add "target/artifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar app.jar"`

What the correct use of Dockerfile's "ADD" semantic when using the fabric8 docker maven plugin?

**The pom** :

```
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>

<image>
                        <name>postgres:9.4</name>
                        <alias>dbstore</alias>
                        <run>
                            <namingStrategy>alias</namingStrategy>
                            <volumes>
                                <bind>/var/lib/postgresql/data</bind>
                            </volumes>
                        </run>
                    </image>
                    <image>
                        <name>private-dockerhub.company.com/dbpath/postgres:latest</name>
                        <alias>data_dump_loader</alias>
                        <run>
                            <namingStrategy>alias</namingStrategy>
                            <ports>
                                <port>5432:5432</port>
                            </ports>

                            <volumes>
                                <from>dbstore</from>
                            </volumes>
                        </run>
                    </image>

                    <image>
                        <name>private-dockerhub.commpany.com/path/reports</name>
                        <alias>reports</alias>
                        <build>
                            <from>private-dockerhub.company.com/core/java:oracle-server-jre8</from>
                            <tags>
                                <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                            </tags>
                            <entryPoint>
                                <arg>java</arg>
                                <arg>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom</arg>
                                <arg>-jar</arg>
                                <arg>/app.jar</arg>
                            </entryPoint>
                        </build>
                        <run>
                            <namingStrategy>alias</namingStrategy>
                            <capAdd>
                                <capAdd>target/reports-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar app.jar</capAdd>
                            </capAdd>
                            <ports>
                                <port>${project.port}:${project.port}</port>
                            </ports>
                            <wait>
                                <!-- The plugin waits until this URL is reachable via HTTP ... -->
                                <http>
                                    <url>http://localdocker:${project.port}/beans</url>
                                    <method>GET</method>
                                    <status>403</status>
                                </http>
                                <!-- ... but at max 10 seconds -->
                                <time>120000</time>
                            </wait>
                            <log>
                              <enabled>true</enabled>
                              <color>red</color>
                            </log>
                            <env>
                                                    <SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL>jdbc:postgresql://localdocker:5432/thedatabase</SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL>
                                <SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME>org.postgresql.Driver</SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME>
                                <SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME>cool-username</SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME>
                                <SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD>secret</SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD>

                            </env>
                            <extraHosts>localdocker:ip.168.99.100</extraHosts>
                        </run>
                    </image>

        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`capAdd` can not be used for adding files to a Docker image. It is meant to set specific Linux capabilities for starting containers. It is the same as the [`--cap-add` cli option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities).

For adding files when **building** images, you have several possibilities as described in the documentation:

- You can use an [assembly](http://fabric8io.github.io/docker-maven-plugin/docker-build.html#docker-assembly) which works much like the maven-assembly-plugin. There are also predefined descriptors for e.g. including your build artefact.
- You can refer to an external Dockerfile (where you can put regular Dockerfile `ADD` commands. This can be triggered by setting a `<build><assembly><dockerFileDir>....` in the configuration (in the next version you can put the `<dockerFileDir>` also directly below (`<build>...</build>`).

So for your example (assuming that your artifact is `reports-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar`) you could try:

```
<build>
   <from>private-dockerhub.company.com/core/java:oracle-server-jre8</from>
   <tags>
      <tag>${project.version}</tag>
   </tags>
   <entryPoint>
      <arg>java</arg>
      <arg>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom</arg>
      <arg>-jar</arg>
      <arg>/app.jar</arg>
   </entryPoint>
   <!-- ============================================ -->
   <assembly>
      <inline>
        <dependencySets>
           <dependencySet>
              <includes>
                <include>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:jar:${project.version}:exec</include>
              </includes>
              <outputFileNameMapping>app.jar</outputFileNameMapping>
           </dependencySet>
        </dependencySets>
      </inline>
   </assembly>
</build>
```

See the documentation of the [descriptor format](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) for details.

If you wouldn't use a classifier `exec`, things would be much easier, though, because then you could use the predefined descriptor `artifact`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I confused capAdd and Add. I should've used an assembly for that. Thanks again.